# Error: CMySQLCursor.executemany() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seq_params'

Tags: python, flask, mysql-connector

I'am working on **flask** application, and I want to initilize the **db** when i start the application, so i create a schema file:

schema.sql file contains:

```
-- Drops
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `article`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `book`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `settings`;

-- Article
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` date,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


-- Book
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `img` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` date,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


-- Settings
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(150) DEFAULT "تَربيَة الأُمةِ مِنْ جَديدٍ",
  `cover_text` varchar(200) DEFAULT "{فَاعْلَمْ أَنَّهُ لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا اللَّهُ}",
  `admin_username` varchar(50) DEFAULT "Admin",
  `admin_password` varchar(50) DEFAULT "12345",
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into `settings`(`title`,`cover_text`,`admin_username`,`admin_password`) values ("تَربيَة الأُمةِ مِنْ جَديدٍ","{فَاعْلَمْ أَنَّهُ لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا اللَّهُ}","Admin","12345");
```

Then i use `**executemany()**` to create my database tables, I write this code:

```
def init_db():
    _,mycursor = mysql_connector()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        mycursor.executemany(f.read().decode('utf8'))
```

But when i run by **`flask --app flaskr init-db`** there's problem with `mycursor.executemany()` function.

The **Error** says:

```
mycursor.executemany(f.read().decode('utf8'))
TypeError: CMySQLCursor.executemany() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seq_params'
```

**Note:** `mysql_connector` function in 1st line of the code is a function return the cursor of the mysql connector:

```
config = {
    data...
}

def mysql_connector():
    try:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            site_logger.exception("Something is wrong with your username or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            site_logger.exception("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print("Error: ", err)
            site_logger.exception(err)
        return
    else:
        # Initialize our cursor
        mycursor = g.db.cursor(buffered=True)
        return g.db, mycursor
```

I tried to change the sql code in **schema.sql** file but the same problem.

So where's the problem or what's the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute different SQL queries one by one but with `executemany()` you execute the same SQL query multiple times.

Modify your code like this

```
def init_db():
    _, mycursor = mysql_connector()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        # Split the file content by semicolon and filter out empty lines
        sql_commands = [cmd.strip() for cmd in f.read().decode('utf8').split(';') if cmd.strip()]

        for cmd in sql_commands:
            mycursor.execute(cmd)
```